# Keep common functions in separate cs file? (C#)

Tags: c#, visual-studio, function, visual-studio-2008

I have a common functions AppPath() that is used in several windows forms of my application, instead of declaring it in each form, I would like to place it in a separate cs file.

I have created a separate class cs file, which I gave a different namespace (modUtilities) and put all functions inside a modUtilities class.

```
namespace modUtilities
{
    public class modUtilities
    {
        // all functions such as AppPath()....
    }
}
```

But I can't figure out how to use function from modUtilities inside different windows forms where I need it. I am trying to use "using modUtilities", instead of creating new instance (modUtilities modU = new modUtilities())
Can someone help me?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

if your methods are static within the class, you can do

```
using modUtilities;
```

then

```
var something = modUtilities.AppPath();
```

if not, you'll need to create an instance of the class.

```
modUtilities mod = new modUtilities();
```