# C# keep common functions in seperate cs file can't find namespace

Tags: c#

First off I'm only creating this question because I can't make comments in the question that has nearly all the info I need. Here is that question so I don't have to duplicate more than I have to:

[Keep common functions in separate cs file? (C#)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17818168/keep-common-functions-in-separate-cs-file-c)

So I followed the info Jonesopolis gave in his answer, but it just throws me an error saying it can't find the namespace on the using GeneralStuff; line.

This is the contents of the cs file I would like to use the function from:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

namespace GeneralStuff
{
    public static class GeneralStuff
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Creates a Unity color object using values 0-255
        /// so getting the color right is easier
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="r"></param>
        /// <param name="g"></param>
        /// <param name="b"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public static Color setColor(float r, float g, float b)
        {

            if (r != 0)
            {
                r = r / 255f;
            }

            if (g != 0)
            {
                g = g / 255f;
            }

            if (b != 0)
            {
                b = b / 255f;
            }

            Color color = new Color(r, g, b);

            return color;
        }

    }
}
```

This cs file is in the same folder as the cs file I would like to use this function in. Yes it is a script in Unity project in case that is relevant. I missing something, but I can't figure out what. Can someone help?

Comment: In the file where you want to use the methods of this static class add the _using GeneralStuff;_ at the beginnng of the file

Comment: I have that it is where the error is thrown. Sorry about not having that in the question I always notice the stuff I missed after I post it.

Comment: Is it included in the project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your second file, you have to have a `using` statement for the namespace you wish to use:

- `[[ other-file.cs ]]`

  ```
  using GeneralStuff;

  namespace SecondFile {
      public class SecondClass {
          public SecondClass() {
              var something = GeneralStuff.setColor(0f,0f,0f);
          }
      }
  }
  ```

**EDIT**: You'll also need to include it in the current project. From [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19862185/visual-studio-using-external-files-without-copying-them):

> 1. Right-click project and select "Add -> Existing Item"
> 2. Navigate to
>      the file you want to add as a link, and select it.
> 3. Look at the "Add"
>      button at lower right of the "Add Existing Item" dialog. It has a
>      little drop arrow.
> 4. Click that drop arrow. Select "Add as link".

Comment: @Eegxeta See the edit - hopefully that solves your issue.